# Unable to show contact image in shortcut items

Tags: ios

We develop an app with some features in iPhone 6s.

I faced some issue when showing the contact image in the shortcut item. I am able to show the dummy image, but I am unable to dynamically fetch the contact image and show in the shortcut items.

My images are in documents directory. I need to show in shortcut item.

```
UIApplicationShortcutIcon iconWithTemplateImageName: --------]
```

I tried this:

```
UIApplicationShortcutIcon * photoIcon = [UIApplicationShortcutIcon iconWithTemplateImageName:SaveImage.png];
```

I can show a direct local image, but I cannot show the image from addressbook.

Any recommendations are welcome.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to fix grammar. I also indented your code sample by 4 spaces so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This question is confusing.  You say your images are "in the documents directory", but you want to display images from the address book.

What I recommend doing is getting the contact you want from the CNContactStore (a [`CNContact` has an image attribute named `imageData`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Contacts/Reference/CNContact_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CNContact/imageData)) and then pass it to UIApplicationShortcutIcon [which has an init method](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationShortcutIcon_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIApplicationShortcutIcon/iconWithContact:) that takes a CNContact as a parameter (which means it would actually use that image).